# requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.190.1', port=7545): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)

Tags: smartcontracts, connection-timeout, ganache

I used Ganache to build a test chain locally, and deployed the smart contract code on this chain.

```
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("HTTP://192.168.190.1:7545"))
```

When I upload very small lists(test CEDB len = 12), the smart contract executes correctly.But when the list I uploaded was larger(test CEDB len = 400), when I called the set_CEDB_batch function of the smart contract, a Read timed out error occurred.

```
for key in test_CEDB:
    u_list.append(key)
    C_0_list.append(test_CEDB[key][0])
    C_1_list.append(test_CEDB[key][1])
    C_2_list.append(test_CEDB[key][2])
    delta_list.append(test_CEDB[key][3])
    tc_list.append(test_CEDB[key][4])
    y_list.append(test_CEDB[key][5])
    # print('CEDB key', type(key), key)
    # print('test_CEDB[key][0]', type(test_CEDB[key][1]),test_CEDB[key][1])

    tx_set_CEDB_batch_hash = store_var_contract.functions.set_CEDB_batch(u_list, C_0_list, C_1_list, C_2_list, y_list,
                                                                         len_test_CEDB).transact({"from": from_account, "gas": 80000000000000, "gasPrice": 0})
```

I want to know how to upload these several large lists to the smart contract normally without a timeout error.